# Docker Container dynamic hosts file

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

Hey fellow overflowdians,

I've started to use Docker to facilitate my local development. However I'm facing an issue. I'm a WP Developer and every time I have to set up a new WP project I have to manually add to my Docker compose file the hostname of the machine using the following:
extra_hosts:

- projectname.local:IP-of-the-container

Well as you know the IP of the container changes per docker container as so as the ID.

So I'm looking for a way to put this into my Docker compose file where it will automatically add the right container IP to the docker hosts file, so that the PHP Docker container can "talk" using the local domain to the frontend webserver nginx, and vice versa?

Any ideas ??

Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: You should be able to use `localhost` and the first `ports:` number from the relevant Compose service.  You should almost never need to manually look up the container IP address (and indeed it only works on one very specific environment).

Comment: Thanks! how would I do that? @DavidMaze